# How to create sql insert scripts from the log file

Tags: sql, node.js, grep

I have a long log file. The log file contains objects like

```
{someData:"", someData1:"", someData2:"", someData3:""}
{someData:"", someData1:"", someData2:"", someData3:""}
{someData:"", someData1:"", someData2:"", someData3:""}
```

My task is to generate SQL inserts from those objects.

Basically I need to generate SQL like this:

```
INSERT table_name (someData, someData1) VALUES (?, ?)
```

The question is: how can I grep the log file and go through all rows, and select only relevant fields for generating the insert methods with values of that fields of object?

Comment: Looks like each row is a json object. You can parse each row/line with any json parser and read each property and add them to variables for your sql query

Comment: [edit] your question to include the complete expected output given that input as right now we're just guessing at what you might want.

Answer (score 0):

Not the prettiest answer, but you could accomplish this using the following awk command line:

```
awk '{ 
printf "insert into table_name ("; 
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { 
        t=$i; sub(/\:\"[^\"]*\"/, "", t); sub("^\{", "", t); sub("\}$", "", t);  printf t 
    }; 
printf ") values ("; 
    for(i=1; i<=NF; i++) { sub(/^(\{)?[^\:]+\:\"/, "\"", $i); sub("\"\}$" , "\"", $i); printf $i }  
print "); " }' yourdatafilename
```

**Explanation:**

*awk* is a command line tool that manipulates text data line by line.

*printf* inside awk expression outputs the value

*for(i=1; i<=NF;i++)* loops over the fields, awk will use space as default separator, so it will see {somedata:"", as the first field, in the first line

*t=$i* making a copy of each field value so I can use inside the for loop

*sub* replaces a regex pattern with a value, in the first case I'm just deleting the undesired parts from the output to keep the column name, and in the second for loop it's deleting the column name keeping only the value.

*yourdatafilename* is the filename argument for awk to read the data from, replace this with yours

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you actually want 3 lines of output given that input, I'd use sed since this is just simple substitutions on individual lines:

```
$ sed 's/{\([^:]*\)[^ ]* \([^:]*\).*/INSERT table_name (\1, \2) VALUES (?, ?)/' file
INSERT table_name (someData, someData1) VALUES (?, ?)
INSERT table_name (someData, someData1) VALUES (?, ?)
INSERT table_name (someData, someData1) VALUES (?, ?)
```

or if you prefer awk:

```
$ awk -F'[{: ]' '{printf "INSERT table_name (%s, %s) VALUES (?, ?)\n", $2, $4}' file
INSERT table_name (someData, someData1) VALUES (?, ?)
INSERT table_name (someData, someData1) VALUES (?, ?)
INSERT table_name (someData, someData1) VALUES (?, ?)
```

but this is definitely not a job for grep. `grep` means `g/re/p`, i.e. globally find the text matching a regexp and print it - it is not for manipulating/changing that text.